# Error message in Chrome, Firefox, Safari "ERR_BAD_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT"

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I've tried everything and read first 10 results of google search result of ERR_BAD_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT. All not working. I am using Mac.

This problem only exists for [angularjs 2](https://angular.io/) official site, which is https.

I don't understand what the certificate is doing. Why do I need a certificate.

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Fix my issue.
Run my angular-cli app under https instead of http
using `ng serve --ssl 1 --ssl-key "my-key.pem" --ssl-cert "my-cert.pem"`